# NSMutableArray loses data

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

There is lots of help regarding this issue already here but none of the implementations have worked. i.e.: creating (nonatomic, retain) + using self.myArray, Using a dictionary instead of arrays.

What I am doing is parsing information from an xml document, filter out unwanted entries, and try to dynamically store the information for that entry.

When I try to store the info into 2 mutableArrays the information of ONE of them gets lost when trying to access the info outside of my 'parser' method.

Some background code. Not full code. (this also has the dictionary as well)

.h

```
@interface WikiView : UIViewController {
    //scrollview
    UIScrollView *ScrollView;

    //init
    int isIpad;
    int orientation;
    int parseCount;

    //parse data constructs
    NSString *subplant;
    NSString *element;
    NSMutableString *text;
    NSString *oldElement;
    NSMutableDictionary *dataHolder;
    NSMutableArray *dataGroup;
    NSMutableArray *dataText;

}
@end
```

.m

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    //inits
    dataGroup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    dataText = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    dataHolder = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

    text = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    //parse the info 
    [self loadDataFromXML:xmlpath];

    //When I call the values for dataText here they are all null
    //also when called the objects for dataHolder are null as well

    //this outputs the correct array
    for (int i = 0; i<[dataGroup count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%@",dataGroup[i]);
    }
    //this outputs an array of null objects
    for (int i = 0; i<[dataText count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"HI.....%@",dataText[i]);
    }
}

//parse function
//method to retrieve data
- (void)loadDataFromXML:(NSString *)xmlpath {
    //data is parsed
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: xmlpath];
    NSXMLParser* parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: data];

    [parser setDelegate:self];

    [parser parse];

    [parser release];
}



//on found characters
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if ([subplant isEqualToString:plantid]) {

        NSString *s2 = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

        if (![oldElement isEqualToString:element]) {

            if (oldElement != nil) {
                if (parseCount >= 1) {

                    //Here I store the values into the proper places

                    NSLog(@"%@: %@",oldElement,text);
                    [dataGroup addObject:oldElement];
                    [dataText addObject:text];
                    [dataHolder setObject:text forKey:oldElement];

                    //The values are correct here
                }
                parseCount++;
            }

            //if (new tag) reset string
            [text setString:s2];
        }
        else{
            //if not new tag append string (takes care of &apos;)
            [text appendString:s2];
        }

        oldElement = element;
    }
}

//on did start element
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    //accessing tags of this element
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"plant"]) {
        subplant = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"plant"];
    }
    element = elementName;
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
    [text release]; [dataGroup release]; [dataText release]; [dataHolder release];
}
```

I create dataGroup and dataText the exact same way but only dataText loses its value.

Any help is appreciated, and if any part of my code is unclear please let me know.

EDIT:

Found the source of the problem.

When I write to the dataText array I rewrite every entry to be the last entry to be entered. In my test case the last entry was the string @"null" creating an array of nulls.

Will be back with solution when found.

EDIT2:

@RuslanSoldatenko Noticed I did not create a new instance of my text string after I set the object in the array. Look at the comments for help.

Comment: What do you mean by "gets lost when trying to access the info"?  Is the entire array deallocated?  Are only some objects missing?

Comment: Please show more context of those declarations in the header file.  They are within an `@interface` declaration, right?

Comment: Also, I see where you `release` the arrays; where do you `retain` them?

Comment: Also: what are the results of running the clang static analyzer?  And, why don't you use ARC?

Comment: Good question on ARC since in Xcode 5.x ARC is the default for new projects.

Comment: May be your problem in `text` object. Post all code where you use it (create, set or something else).

Comment: What I mean by "lost" is when I access the arrays in the initnibwithname method the array is full of null objects. Also I am new to objective c and do not understand ARC.

Comment: Code has been updated to reflect questions in the comments.

Comment: @RuslanSoldatenko Yes I believe that is the case. Is there any reason the mutableString is not transferring outside of the method? or could it be the way I am appending/setting the "text" string?

Comment: After `[dataHolder setObject:text forKey:oldElement];` in `foundCharacters:` method you need create new instance for `text`. Add `text = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];` In non ARC project may be you need add `[text release]` before it (I`m not sure).

Comment: @user3009729 if you are brand new to Objective-C then enable ARC. It will make everything easier.